# PTVS broken on VS2015 community Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ptvs

I cannot make Python tools working on VS2015. I reinstalled VS several times and enable/disable the Python tools several times.
[image]

I cannot open a .sln with a pyprojc
it says 
".pyproj : error  : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having that error when I've updated PTVS (installed from VS Extensions and Updates) to PTVS from Release Github.

Comment: Hi Kohen, I think I updated the visual studio 2 months ago and the error was no longer there.. I'm not sure if this will fix your case..

Comment: Wasn't easy as well, but through multiple VS Repair, reinstalling VS to Update 1, and later on re-updating to Update 2, it also somehow fixed my issue. Here's the steps I've went through in case others are having similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37955825/761543