# VS2015.3/PTVS Python Tools no longer working?

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

**strong text**I reinstalled **VS 2015 Update 3** (from Web install) w/Python Tools, but Python Tools don't seem to work anymore. From ActivityLog.xml, the error is:

```
<record>494</record>
<time>2016/07/04 15:59:16.031</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Python Tools
             Package]Source:
&apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition&apos; 
Description: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name
&quot;Microsoft.PythonTools.Interpreter.IInterpreterOptionsService&quot;
but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.
#x000D;&#x000A;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: 
Expected 1 export(s) with contract name 
&quot;Microsoft.PythonTools.Interpreter.IInterpreterOptionsService&quot; 
but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.&#x000D;&#x000A;   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports
(ImportDefinition importDefinition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports
[T,TMetadataView](String contractName, ImportCardinality 
cardinality)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport
[T,TMetadataView]       (String contractName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T]
(String   contractName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T]
()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue
[T]  ()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService
[T]  ()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
Microsoft.PythonTools.PythonToolsService..ctor(IServiceContainer
container)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at   
Microsoft.PythonTools.PythonToolsPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;
at  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.
Interop.IVs    Package.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
<guid>{6DBD7C1E-1F1B-496D-AC7C-C55DAE66C783}</guid>
<hr>80131500</hr> <errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

I de-installed/re-installed VS 2015 Python support (directly from PTVS 2.2.4 VS 2015.msi). Same error.

---

What to do? The Machine (Win 10) has Python 2.7/x64 in PATH.

**There seems to be a real problem for other too**. See here:
[Visual Studio Python Environments window does not display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37721461/170194)

Interestingly, I have two similar dev machines (Win10/x64), both installed recently, both have VS 2013Pro + VS2015 Community installed. **On one box, everything works fine**, on the other: see above.

Comment: I received the same error as well when I tried to install the June update for PTVS. It removed the March install and then started giving the error. I didn't choose to install Update 3 yet.

Answer (score 15):

Had the same issue. 
Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, PTVS 2.2.4

Resolved it by:

1. Closing VS
2. Clearing the content of C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache folder. * notice the YOUR_USERNAME and replace it with your actual username to get the local path.
3. Relaunching VS.

Hope this helps

Comment: you are a super hero

Comment: Had this issue today VS2017 and this worked like charm. Just replace 14.0 to 15.0

Answer (score 1):

Delete the contents from the following folders:

```
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

and run Visual Studio 2015 again:

```
[x64] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
[x86] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they fixed these issues in PTVS 2.2.5: github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1411 and github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1415

Answer (score -1):

Control Panel/Uninstall change
Select VS2015, click change

Once the dialog builds, select modify, then select Python tools.

Done.

Comment: If I "select" Python tools, which is already [X] selected, I [  ] deselect and uninstall it. How would this help?